# python print str.decode("utf-8") UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, decode

I want to convert a python string (utf-8) to unicode.

```
word = "3——5" # —— is u'\u2013', not a english symbol
print type(word).__name__ # output is str
print repr(word)          # output is '3\xe2\x80\x935'
print word.decode("utf-8", errors='ignore')
```

I got this error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But when I change

```
word.decode("utf-8", errors='ignore')
```

to

```
word.decode(errors='ignore')
```

the error disappears.

Why? word is a utf-8 string, why can't i specify utf-8 to decode?

Comment: Is this python2?

Comment: yes, it is python2.7

Comment: Well, it seems like your encoding is _not_ `utf-8`. It could be `latin-1`. Try: `word.decode('latin-1', errors='ignore')`

Comment: type(word).__name__ is str, str doesn't mean it is a utf-8 string ?

Comment: Well, I'm using py2.7 and I get no errors:

    Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
    [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> word = "3——5"
    >>> word.decode("utf-8")
    u'3\u2014\u20145'

Comment: That would be the case with python3, but not python2.

Comment: OP is expecting it to be u\2013 though, not two \u2014. Maybe copy-pasting from here does some conversion too.

Comment: o, ok. I didn't thought about that

Comment: What does `print repr(word)` produce?

Comment: print repr(word)  --> '3\xe2\x80\x935'

Comment: That is exactly the same that I get with u'3\u20135'.encode('utf-8'), so by all logic the conversion should work the other way too.

Comment: The cause is the `print`.  Your Linux terminal isn't configured correctly.  What is your `LANG` environment variable?  If you just use `x = word.decode('utf8')` it should work.

Comment: Mark Tolonen is right, the cause is the 'print'.

Comment: Make sure `LANG=en_US.utf-8`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Maybe you want to write an answer based on your comments?